# Override GraphQL Default Status Code(200) With Different Code Thrown By Service In Case Of Exception

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I have a micro-service build on top of SpringBoot and I am using GraphQL for the micro services. By default GraphQL sends 200 status code even though its an error and error details comes as part of the error section in response.

But I wanted to send different status code when the transaction is not success and thrown an exception by the service.

How can I achieve that ? Can someone help me on that ?

My current custom exception class is of type GraphQLError.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to GraphQL [standards](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Errors), any errors should return in `error` block, so you should return status code, the message in erorr block

> The errors entry in the response is a non‐empty list of errors, where each error is a map.

> If no errors were encountered during the requested operation, the errors entry should not be present in the result.

> If the data entry in the response is not present, the errors entry in the response must not be empty. It must contain at least one error. The errors it contains should indicate why no data was able to be returned.

> If the data entry in the response is present (including if it is the value null), the errors entry in the response may contain any errors that occurred during execution. If errors occurred during execution, it should contain those errors.

```
{
   "errors": [
       {
           "message": "error message",
           "path": "/api/call",
           "status_code": 500
       }
   ],
    "data": null
}
```

Comment: I understand the GraphQL standard but my question here is, can i override the default status code with the status code thrown by service in case of exception ?

Comment: i will say you should not, and i'm not sure if there is a way to do that @DebapriyaPatra

Comment: @DebapriyaPatra am also looking for the same thing, were you able to find any solution?

Comment: this is my question too. if you found any solution please share it.

Comment: If you want to send diff status code then you should not choose graphql, you can use HTTP RESTFULL API's